# Prior distribution on/of a parameter

Tags: bayesian, terminology

Is it correct to write *the prior distribution **on** $\mu$* ?

I think it is correct because it refers to the fact that *"we put a distribution on (the state space of) $\mu$"*.

However, I would *not* say *the posterior distribution **on** $\mu$*.

This is how I feel it but my feeling is based on the French translation. Is it correct in English ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being that the first two results of a Google search (in English) for "prior distribution on" [yield](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf) [papers](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/p039-_o.pdf) by Andrew Gelman, I'm sufficiently convinced that "on" is common enough not to cause confusion. Actually, there are contexts in which using "**of**" would strike some native English speakers as odd. For instance, the phrase "a uniform prior **of** $log(\sigma$)"—rather than "**on** $log(\sigma)$," as it reads in one of the Gelman papers—sounds a bit off to my ear. More, "posterior on" is used commonly throughout

So, whether a matter of technical definition or simple convention, it's acceptable. My own bias is to use "on" more frequently than "of," and in some cases I've even seen "for."

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use **on** instead of **of**?

I think that **of** is more correct because it refers to the fact that we are talking about the distribution **of** $\mu$ ***before*** (prior -> pre -> before) --- the observation of data.

Similarly, I think it is correct "posterior distribution **of** $\mu$", because it refers to the distribution of $\mu$ ***after*** (posterior -> post -> after) we have observed data.

Comment: There is no doubt that **of** is correct. My question is about the correctness of **on** and its meaning. I consider the meaning of **on** as similar to : *"a distance on a metric space"*. That means the metric space is equipped with a distance. In the Bayesian context, that would mean the state space of $\mu$ is equipped with the prior distribution. As I said in my OP: *we put a distribution **on** (the state space of) $\mu$"*.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I see. (+1) for the interesting point!